# Want to run eclipse phonegap 2.7 project through phonegap desktop app for android

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to use phonegap desktop app for debugging.Want to use phonegap 2.7 eclipse project to run through phonegap desktop app

Comment: OK good. [Go look at their website](https://cordova.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

For testing phonegap, I used the chrome extension Ripple Emulator, and used phonegap serve command from the terminal. I then went to localhost:3000 and enabled the Ripple Emulator for that page.

Check it out here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en